# google drive api get updated list of documents

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, quartz-scheduler

I am preparing a demo in which I have a situation that I have to write a scheduler (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) that runs every 10 minutes to fetch new uploaded documents from Google drive. I am using google drive api, Can anyone please share some tutorials or links that achieve this task.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the search functionality for this.
More info on https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters

The query would be something like 'modifiedDate > "2016-07-19 13:47" ' for example.
This would also contain all modified files, not only the new files though.

Anything specific you need more help with?

Comment: Actually upon request after every 10 minutes I need to get only those files that are being newly added. Is it possible that I can get only the list of files that are newly added or can you guide me about any workaround to know that the file is added newly?

Comment: Files have a createdDate property. So if you loop over the list of files returned by the searchquery above you could see which files have been created and which one were only modified. see https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files